# Test notification sending

Tags: .net, azure, testing, notifications, push-notification

I'm currently developing Notification Server that uses Windows Azure Notification Hubs and faced with the next problem.

I need to implement test notification sending, I mean when notification is sent, it should be shown only on test versions (which aren't in Windows Store).
I decide to use Tag sending and separate channel creating logic (for testing I created channel with "Test" tag, for production I create broadcast channel). For now, I want to simplify this procedure and make automated channel creating mechanism. But I have no ideas how to determine from code with which build I work with (Test or Production, from Windows Store). 
If someone coped with it or has any ideas how to organize test sending, please advice me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try conditional compilation. For Release configuration create channel without tags but with "test" tag for Debug.